# How can I fix my CSS code to work with IE (where it shows scroll bars)?

Tags: html, css, browser, scrollbar

I have the following CSS code, works fine with Firefox, Chrome but breaks like hell when I run it in IE7!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Box Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        .mybox  { float:left;  overflow:auto; visibility:visible;
          width:220px; height:100px; 
          margin:3px; padding:10px; 

          border-left:1px solid gray; border-right:1px solid black; 
          border-top:1px solid gray;  border-bottom:1px solid black; 
          background-color:gold; }

    .small { width:45px; height:auto; font-weight:bold;}

    .boxfont{font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; margin-left:15px;} 

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

     <div class="mybox small">
    box 1
        <div class="boxfont">box1 label</div>
      </div>

     <div class="mybox small">box 2</div>

     <div class="mybox small">box 3</div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Why do i get scroll bars on the first box in IE7 and NOT in any other browser?

Comment: See this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927626/how-do-you-deal-with-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `overflow:auto` in `.mybox` but I can't test it because I do not have access to IE7 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Either increase the width of `.mybox` to `60px` or set `overflow:hidden`. This is because IE7 show the scrollbars with a different calculation of width, it is highly annoying...

Answer (score 1):

.small has a width of 45px and left and right padding of 10px. .boxfont has a left-margin of 15px.

45px-10px-10px-15px leaves you with only 10px of space for your text.  The other browsers are showing the text, IE is putting in the scrollbars.

Put `overflow:hidden` on .boxfont to see where it is cut off in Firefox.

To fix this, you can put `overflow:visible` on .small to have IE show the text but that will make your box a little bigger. Or you can just increase the width of your box a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experieinceing is due to the [IE Box Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) issue.
You can fix the display issue in your code by replacing the .boxfont definition as below.

```
.boxfont{font-weight:bold; font-size:16px; margin-left:10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the `overflow:auto` property it can work. But better you [setup IE7 cross css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332325/can-you-switch-off-xss-protection-in-ie7-so-that-an-intranet-application-can-kno) to fix the scroll bar issue.