# how to solve the automatic zoom-in problem in websites?

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

My webpage gets automatically zoomed-in only in Macbook pro. I get the actual size only if zoom-out the webpage in browser manually.

I have set the initial scale and device width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

I'm trying to fix it by setting the zoom property to 80%. How to set only to macbook pro? Is there any other solution to this problem.

Comment: You want set zoom level for entire website `80%` in macbook?

Comment: how to set the zoom property only for macbookpro ?

Comment: Try `zoom:80%` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860745/css-hack-for-safari-only

Comment: I want to set this property only for macbook pro.Is there any possibilities?

Comment: I think possible only. check the stack link they explained the code based on browser version.

Comment: i think this problem is not based on browser versions.Because webiste works fine in every broswer in every laptop.This problem only occurs in MacBook Pro 13inch.

Comment: Oh. Then problem with Mac settings?. Its seems like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)