# How to avoid running ant tasks on source files that have not changed?

Tags: ant

I have an `ant` task that executes some command on a list of files.
I would like, on consecutive builds, to avoid from re-running the command on files that have passed the command with success and haven't changed.

For example: (here the command is `xmllint`)

```
 <target name="xmllint-files">
    <apply executable="xmllint">
        <srcfile/>
        <fileset dir="." includes="*.xml">
            <modified/>
        </fileset>

    </apply>
</target>
```

The problem is that even the files where `xmlint` fails are considered as modified and therefore `xmllint` will not be re-run on them on consecutive builds. Obviously, this is not the desired behavior.

Two remarks:

1. I am looking for a general solution and not only a solution for `xmllint`.
2. I want to solve the problem totally inside `ant` without creating
   external scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code uses the [Groovy ANT task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to do the following:

- Implement a custom groovy selector, selecting the XML files to be processed based on a MD5 checksum check.
- Invoke **xmllint** on each file and store it's checksum upon successful completion (This prevents re-execution of **xmllint** unless the file's contents are changed.

Example:

```
<project name="demo" default="xmllint">

    <!--
    ======================
    Groovy task dependency
    ======================
    -->
    <path id="build.path">
        <pathelement location="jars/groovy-all-1.8.6.jar"/>
    </path>
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <!--
    ==============================================
    Select files to be processed 
    MD5 checksums located in "checksums" directory
    ==============================================
    -->
    <target name="select-files">
        <fileset id="unprocessedfiles" dir=".">
            <include name="*.xml"/>
            <exclude name="build.xml"/>
            <scriptselector language="groovy" classpathref="build.path">
                def ant = new AntBuilder()
                ant.checksum(file:filename, toDir:"checksums", verifyProperty:"isMD5ok")

                self.selected = (ant.project.properties.isMD5ok == "false") ? true : false
            </scriptselector>
        </fileset>
    </target>

    <!--
    =============================================================
    Process each file 
    Checksum is saved upon command success, prevents reprocessing
    =============================================================
    -->
    <target name="xmllint" depends="select-files">
        <groovy>
            project.references.unprocessedfiles.each { file ->
                ant.exec(executable:"xmllint", resultproperty:"cmdExit") {
                    arg(value:file)
                }
                if (properties.cmdExit == "0") {
                    ant.checksum(file:file.toString(), toDir:"checksums")
                }
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```

**Note**:

- This complex requirement cannot be implemented using the original **apply** ANT task. One call to *xmllint* command might succeed whereas another might fail.
- A subdirectory called "checksums" is created to store the MD5 checksum files.
- The groovy jar can be downloaded from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.groovy%7Cgroovy-all%7C1.8.6%7Cjar)

---

## Original answer

Use the ANT [modified selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#modified)

```
<project name="demo" default="xmllint">

    <target name="xmllint">
        <apply executable="xmllint">
            <srcfile/>
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.xml">
                <modified/>
            </fileset>
        </apply>
    </target>

</project>
```

A property file called "cache.properties" will be created in the build directory. It records file digests, used determine if the file has been changed since the last build run.

Comment: The problem is even if the task fails, the build will not re-run that file. I need to avoid re-run only on files that have passed the build.

Comment: That's not what you asked. My only suggestion is a custom selector. In addition to the file digest (to signify file changes) you'll also need to store the result of the operation.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't work. Look at the updated code snippet in the question and reproduce like this: Create a non-valid xml file. Run ant twice. On the 2nd time, the `xmllint` doesn't run on the file. Please help.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work.... A mechanism exists to detect changes to the file (ANT "modified" selector). Problem is, as you've outlined in your original question, how do you propose to **additionally** record the previous success of the operation, for each file.... All this with standard ANT.... Let me chew over it, not sure how it can be done without writing scripted extensions to ANT.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit I've updated my answer. New solution requires the groovy plugin

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would like a simpler solution. I think that if I get an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/927802/813665, I could build an elegant solution with `mapper`: I will write a custom task that touches a target file upon success. What do you think Mark?

Comment: Can't comment on the other link, seems unrelated..... Creating an output file after successfully running the command would certainly simplify things. Then you'd be able to use the much simpler solution of a **present** selector (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect).

Comment: The problem is that I don't how to use `apply` with a `task` instead of an `executable`. Because I prefer not to have to use external scripts. This is the connection with the other question. Could you help on it?